# What is the difference between deploy and promote and release in Sonatype Nexus Pro?

Tags: maven, build, release, nexus, staging

I am new to Nexus Pro. I am trying to understand the difference between deploy, promote and release in Nexus Pro.

My understanding is that to move the tested/approved artifacts from Staging to Release repository we do promote. But why are there different buttons for promote and release in Nexus Pro?